# uncrustify adds space between double-parenthesis (C/Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

I'm having a very peculiar issue with uncrustify (v0.60) that no option seems to affect. The issue only occurs when there are parenthesis enclosed within parenthesis:

```
// from a C header file:
#define BEGIN_STACK_MODIFY(L)  int __index = lua_gettop( (L) );
                                                        ^   ^

// from an ObjC (.m) implementation file:
if ( (self = [super init]) )
    ^                     ^
```

I want to reformat those to look like this, but uncrustify always adds those spaces between parenthesis (when I manually reformat to the code below, uncrustify will reformat it to the version above, so it's not just being ignored by uncrustify):

```
// from an ObjC header file:
#define BEGIN_STACK_MODIFY(L)  int __index = lua_gettop((L));

// from an ObjC (.m) implementation file:
if ((self = [super init]))
```

I used UncrustifyX to check all (well, a great number of) variations of possibly related settings for spaces and parenthesis with no luck.

You can check my [uncrustify config file here on gist](https://gist.github.com/LearnCocos2D/5474209).

If you have any idea what settings I should try, or perhaps settings that may be in conflict with each other, I'd be happy to test it.

Comment: I think you have parenthesis-ception!

Comment: No, I just have this itching crust on my code. Oh wait … I'm dreaming, am I?

Comment: sp_paren_paren is the option you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answering so that this question no longer appears as unanswered on the front page.)

As @Petesh said in the comments: `sp_paren_paren` is the option you're looking for.